# utf-8 string getting truncated in MySQL table using Perl/DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8, dbi

I am trying to write utf-8 strings to a MySQL table using perl/DBI.  For some reason the string is getting truncated at the first non-ascii character.

For example, if I set up the following table:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE testdb.testtable (textval CHAR(30)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And then run the following perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:host=localhost;database=testdb', 'testuser', 'somepassword', {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO testtable (textval) VALUES ('the N\xFCrburgring')");
```

It actually writes "the N". (when it should be writing "the Nürburgring")

Looking in the MySQL query log, I see this:

```
271 Query INSERT INTO testtable (textval) VALUES ('the Nürburgring')
```

So the string is reaching the DB server intact.

If I enter the same query directly in the MySQL console:

```
INSERT INTO testtable (textval) VALUES ('the Nürburgring');
```

The entire string is written correctly.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And what does it write if you change `\xFC` to `ü` in your script?

Comment: It does exactly the same thing if i use a literal ü in the perl code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the attribute `mysql_enable_utf8`, so you promised the interface that you will give it a Perl string of characters. However, this is a buffer of octets in Latin1 encoding.

```
use Devel::Peek qw(Dump);
Dump "the N\xfcrburgring";
#  FLAGS = (POK,READONLY,pPOK)
#  PV = 0x208e4f0 "the N\374rburgring"\0
```

The fix is simple. Either notate literal characters without `\x` escapes, use the `utf8` pragma to tell Perl that your source code is in UTF-8 and save the source in UTF-8 encoding with your editor…

```
use utf8;
use Devel::Peek qw(Dump);
Dump "the Nürburgring";
#  FLAGS = (POK,READONLY,pPOK,UTF8)
#  PV = 0x20999f0 "the N\303\274rburgring"\0 [UTF8 "the N\x{fc}rburgring"]
```

… or decode the octets into a string. Most of the time you're dealing not with literals, but with data coming from the outside, so better [learn about the whole topic of encoding](http://p3rl.org/UNI).

```
use Encode qw(decode);
use Devel::Peek qw(Dump);
Dump decode 'Latin1', "the N\xfcrburgring";
#  FLAGS = (TEMP,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
#  PV = 0x208f6b0 "the N\303\274rburgring"\0 [UTF8 "the N\x{fc}rburgring"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think I get it now.  I changed the insert line to `$dbh->do(decode('Latin1', "INSERT INTO testtable (textval) VALUES ('the N\xFCrburgring')"));` and now it works perfectly.